# Is there any term for a person who has changed his name?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any term for a person who has changed his name? For example, there was a man who was named "Jacob" when he was born, but when he reached the age of 18 he decided to change his name to "Joseph". Is there any term for this kind of person? Or at least for this kind of practice?

Comment: The Artist Formerly Known as Prince.

Comment: @JLG - lol. Of course that was just said because he used an unpronounceable name (as a clever way to get back at a record company he was contractually obligated to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is "renamed" and the practice is called "renaming" as we read in legal documents.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when such changes aren't totally unexpected, (eg: a woman changing her last name upon marriage), the old name is often appended to the new one with a "nee" in the middle. Supposedly this is French for "born as", so it could reasonably be applied in *any* situation where a person's birth name has been changed.

Comment: [wiktionary says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nee) "When used for a man, the masculine form né should be used."

Comment: I *almost* got into that. That's the rule *in French*. However, we generally don't borrow the gender rules of words when we borrow the words in English. So in the few times you see this "in the wild" attached to a man's name in English, you will typically see both `e`s. People who know the loaner language tend to take the position that we ought to borrow the rules along with the words we borrow, so I'm not surprised to see someone arguing that.